Modeling sequences in the Z3 python API
I was following the Z3 sequences tutorial here: https://microsoft.github.io/z3guide/docs/theories/Sequences/ Would anyone know if there is a similar tutorial on modeling sequences in the Z3 Python API, instead of the SMTLIB format at that link? Thank you in advance!

I don't think there's a dedicated z3py sequence tutorial. But there are many questions/answers on stack overflow that can get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bz3py%5D+sequence
Stack-overflow works the best if you try something out and ask specific programming questions; Questions asking for tutorials/software etc. are out-of-scope.

Thank you for the response! Will look at the link you pasted.
